# What is the plural of "Starbucks"?

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number

I was travelling, and I was standing in a spot where I could see three [Starbucks](http://www.starbucks.com/) shops. Rather than thinking "North American cultural imperialism", my brain had a melt down over what the plural of "Starbucks" was?

[Some](https://nonsequiteuse.wordpress.com/2009/09/18/grammar-police-plural-of-starbucks/) [Googling](http://opinion.latimes.com/opinionla/2008/07/bottom-up.html) suggests "Starbuckses" but that sounds awkward to my ear (well, hearing aid).

Is Starbucks already plural?

Comment: "Starbuckses" is **not** awkward -- "Starbuckses" **it is**, according to grammatical convention, according to usage.

Comment: cf. "Keeping up with the Joneses," etc.

Comment: @Kris Actually, when the singular form of a word ends in consonant + 'S', the plural form is often the same as the singular. For example: ***barracks, crossroads, headquarters, means, series, species, works***. There's no reason why starbucks shouldn't be a member of this group. I've just done a poll of the staffroom here and they are unanimous that it should be *two Starbucks* and not *two Starbuckses*

Comment: @kris, so it looks as though both are ok. The one American English speaker here, who's just come in reckons it's Starbuckses, maybe it's a pond thing.

Comment: Thanks @Kris & Araucaria.  I suspect this might be a AE vs BE divide.  To my (Australian) ear, it sounds awkward... and my (American) hearing aid isn't doing the translation properly. :-)

Comment: @Araucaria: *barracks, crossroads, headquarters, means, works* are all plurals which have become singulars, and many of them are still sometimes treated as plural. And *species* and *series* were Latin words where the plural was the same as the singular. But you're right; there's no reason not to treat *Starbucks* the same way.

Comment: Curiously enough, the plural of *Starbucks* is actually *Meese*.

Comment: @Araucaria I think that rule generally does _not_ apply to proper names.

Comment: What is the possessive of the plural of Starbucks? That is, something that belongs to all the instances of a Starbucks?

Comment: If it was spelled *Starbux* and not *Starbucks*, the plural would be *Starbuxes*, wouldn't it? I think English spelling tends to avoid singular words ending in 'Cs', where 'C' is a consonant: *box, lapse, copse, glimpse, quartz, waltz*.

Comment: One could understand "two Starbucks" as a couple of coffees and "two Starbuckses" to be places where you get them. :)

Comment: @Kris: Yes, I linked to that in my original question.

Comment: Oh! Deleting the comment.

Comment: ODO thinks the Trademark is **singular**: Starbucks™
 "a US make of coffee sold by the Starbucks Coffee Company in its restaurants and shops around the world. The company's main office is in Seattle." http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/starbucks

Comment: The word *starbuck* is unrelated to the coffee company or its product(s). See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starbucks and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starbuck

Comment: +1 We haven’t quite got there yet, but when the day does arrive when one can see three Starbucks from any given point on Earth perhaps the rule concerning the treatment of uncountable nouns ending in “S” will apply!  Thank goodness there wasn’t a “Little Caesars” next to each of those Starbucks (but then again maybe the “rule” concerning the pluralisation of proper nouns ending in “hard Z” sounds would have made that question easier to answer)!

Comment: Many major companies have branding guides which explain this sort of thing in great detail. Have you tried asking Starbucks? But you may not wish to trust such branding guides as they often don't accord with popular usage (e.g. Adobe will tell you not to use "Photoshop" as a verb).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Starbucks" comes, as far as I know, from the possessive, i.e. "Starbuck's Coffee", as it was named after the character Starbuck from *Moby Dick*. With that in mind, it makes sense to me to use "Starbucks" as that would be the same as the plural possessive.

However, I know I've heard "Starbuckses" plenty in conversation. So as far as Southern American usage, that seems fine.

Comment: Thanks! Good answer. That sounds equivocal, but understandable.  I'll wait a bit more before giving a tick.

Answer (score 2):

Starbucks is the name of a company.  You didn't see three major corporations on the corner, but three Starbucks stores.  So here, Starbucks is more of a description than a noun.  Yes, you elide out the "stores" for convenience but that doesn't make it an appropriate noun.

If you saw three stores painted blue, you wouldn't be worried about if you should say that you saw three *"blueses"* at once. You would just say I saw three blue stores and be done.

Comment: The trouble I have with this answer is that "blue" is an adjective, but "Starbucks" is generally used as a noun, so I don't think your analogy quite works. I don't think I've ever heard anyone refer to a "Starbucks store" just a "Starbucks". No vote, just comment.

Answer (score 0):

The singular of "Starbucks" is really "Starbucks Cafe".  The plural would be "Starbucks cafes", so the "Starbucks" part remains unchanged.

Similarly, the plural of "beer" is "beer".  I will have a [pint of/glass of/bottle of] beer.

I will have three [pints of/glasses of/bottles of] beer.

Aspirin was the same at one time but by usage is not any longer.

Singular was:  Aspirin [tablet]
Plural was:  Aspirin [tablets]
Plural currently:  Aspirins

Comment: How is this different from @Oldcat's answer?

Answer (score -1):

"Starbucks" is a noun. According to the grammar, all the nouns which end in "s" will require an "-es" for the plural, so, possibly it is "Starbuckses".

Moreover, it is possible to try to find words which sound similar (poetical approach :-)) or have morphological similarities. There is the word "buck" which has the plural "bucks" (like the basketball club: "Milwaukee Bucks").

Answer (score -1):

Matrix > Matrices

Starbucks > Starbuces

Comment: While creative, for the purposes of this site, EL&U seeks authoritative answers backed by references.  Please see the [tour] and [help].

Comment: Well, that was certainly original. How would you pluralize Chipotles?